# Cierre automatico de una ventana Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy programando un Script y me encontre con este problema que no se resolver.
Imaginemos que hay una pagina que yo quiero logearme, clickeo el boton logearse y me abre una pestaña emergente para logear un usuario y contraseña, la manipulo sin problemas con driver.switch_to.window(handles[1]) al rellenar el formulario y tocar en el boton "Login" esta pestaña se cierra automaticamente, el problema es que no solo se cierra la emergente sino que la ventana principal tambien y mi idea es volver a la pagina principal para seguir con el script. Me podrian ayudar a saber como hacer para volver a la pagina principal sin que se cierre?

Comment: Tendrás que emular las pulsaciones de teclado para cambiar de pestaña (`Keys.CONTROL+”t”`) o cerrar pestaña (`Keys.CONTROL + 'w'`). Para este tipo de automatizaciones te aconsejo [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/pages).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Algo que no recuerdo cómo hacer pero se que se puede, es guardar las cookies de sesión para que una vez logueado no tengas que volver a hacerlo, pero depende de las políticas del server, lo más común es que la sesión dure 24hs

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer webdriver no detecta la pestaña emergente que están separadas, por esto al ingresar:

driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])

y luego el comando close, al no detectar una pestaña nueva cierra la pestaña principal, y esta al cerrarse el resto de tu codigo no funcionara correctamente, esto podría darte una pista.

yo tampoco tengo una solución a esto, debido a que llegue a este post también buscando una.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución,primero declaras la primera pestaña abierta como la original.

```
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
```

con lo siguiente, si hay mas pestañas, comprobara la que tiene el foco actualmente

```
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
     if window_handle != original_window:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break
```

y ya con esto ultimo cierras la pestaña, y declara la que tiene el foco ahora como la original

```
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
```

Espero te haya servido, y disculpas por la mala sintaxis, es la primera ves que encuentro este foro.
Un saludo.